# gherkin.parser.ParseError in a good-looking file

Tags: java, parsing, cucumber, gherkin

Gherkin fails with
`gherkin.parser.ParseError: Parse error at some.feature:5. Found comment when expecting one of: examples, feature, scenario, scenario_outline, tag. (Current getState: tag)` with a some.feature that begins with

```
# language: ru

@atag
@anothertag
#@done

Функционал: Некая фича
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could not survive a comment inside tag section. Removing `#@done` did the job.

So one does not simply add comments into gherkin feature file, and the location of comment have meaning.

Comment: If you dont want to run a tag, you can use the "~@done" in your cucumber options, so no need to comment that out

Comment: @Dude thanks for the knowledge, but it's not the case. I do want all features with "@done" tag to run, and want to temporarily turn one feature off (by commenting the tag).